# the meaning of "e" in matlab output

Tags: matlab, notation

In matlab, especially when testing a neural network, we see a special type of output. for example, `3.332e-23` or `5.e-235`. What is the meaning of "e" in the context of the output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is scientific notation, where `e` is shorthand for `*10^`.

You can change the output type in the console using the [format](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/format.html;jsessionid=14f065cda4d9d1215ad62442cacb#inputarg_Style) command. For example . . .

```
>> x = 1.123456e5

x =

   1.1235e+05

>> format long
>> x

x =

     1.123456000000000e+05

>> format longG
>> x

x =

                  112345.6

>> format hex
>> x

x =

   40fb6d999999999a
```

Answer (score 7):

It's [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation). *AeB* denotes *A x 10<sup>B</sup>*.